# Google maps bicycle navigation

Tags: google-maps

A year back, when I opened "Directions" on my phone, below the start and end point, where 4 options:

- Driving
- Public transport
- Walking
- Cycling

Now cycling is replaced by "Ride Services" which I never use, and do not care about. How can I get "Cycling" back?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From [Google maps support](https://support.google.com/maps/thread/12386678?hl=en&msgid=27708455), Platinum product expert treebles says (2/5/20)

> If your issue is that the bicycling mode of transportation is not available to you, it means that it is not available in your country. There are few countries where this mode of transporation is enabled.

In the same thread you find instances of it being available earlier but not anymore.

- So, Google decides when and where to activate and they [won't tell you list of countries in which it is available :(](https://support.google.com/maps/thread/34058661?hl=en)

> Sadly there's no list of supported areas and Google never announces where it's rolling out beforehand.